# showing multiple details view at a time in ipad design layout

Tags: ios7, uipageviewcontroller, ipad

I am new to iPad development (not on iPhone though), need to show multiple list view in a way 'Reeder' iPad app is showing, is it a modification of SplitViewController or some custom control that they are using?

Snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This kind of layout is not supported by `UISplitView`. It should be a made in custom by putting multiple table-views in a hosting view.

Comment: can u recall any example app using this kind of multiple levels?

Comment: implemented it using views, pan gestures